# React useState hook is not working when submitting form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to React and I have some doubt regarding useState hook.I was recently working on an API based recipe react app .The problem I am facing is when I submit something in search form a state change should happen but the state is not changing but if I resubmit the form the state changes.

```
   import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
   import Form from "./componnents/form";
   import RecipeBlock from "./componnents/recipeblock"
   import './App.css';


   function App() {


     const API_id=process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_ID;
     const API_key=process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY;
     const [query,setQuery]=useState("chicken");

    const path=`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${API_id}&app_key=${API_key}`


    const [recipe,setRecipe]=useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  console.log("use effect is running")
  getRecipe(query);
  

  }, []);

function search(queryString){

 setQuery(queryString);

 getRecipe();

 }

  async function getRecipe(){
    const response=await fetch(path);
    const data=await response.json();

    setRecipe(data.hits);
    console.log(data.hits);

}
```

queryString in search() function holds the value of form input,Every time I submit the form this value is coming correctly but setQuery(queryString) is not changing the query value or state and if I resubmit the form then it change the state.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided something doesn't make sense.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("use effect is running")
  getRecipe(query);
  

  }, []);
```

Your getRecipe doesn't take a variable. But from what I am understanding whenever you search you want to set the Query then get the recipe from that Query.

With the useEffect you can pass in a parameters to check if they changed before running a function. So update the setQuery then when the component reloads it will fire the useEffect if query has changed. Here is the code to explain:

```
  useEffect(() => {
  console.log("use effect is running")
  getRecipe(query);    <-- this doesn't make sense on your code 
  

  }, [query]);

function search(queryString){

 setQuery(queryString);
 }
```

By doing this when the state updates it causes the component to re-render and therefore if query has changed it will call your getRecipe function.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to update my getRecipe() function

Comment: No worries if you could upvote and accept the answer that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you are running `getRecipe()` directly after `setQuery(queryString)`. `setQuery(queryString)` is asynchronous and will queue a state change. When you then run `getRecipe()` directly after, the state will still hold the old value of `query` (and `path`) and therefore does not fetch the new data correctly.

One solution would be to call `getRecipe()` within a `useEffect()` dependent on `path`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getRecipe();
}, [path]);

function search(queryString){
  setQuery(queryString);
  // getRecipe() <- removed
}
```

With `[path]` given as dependencies for `useEffect()`, `getRecipe()` will be called automatically whenever `path` changes. So we don't have to call it manually from `search()` and therefore can remove `getRecipe()` from the function body. This also makes the current `useEffect()` (without `[path]` dependency) redundant, so it can be removed.

Another solution would be to provide the new `query` value through the `getRecipe()` parameters, removing the dependency upon the state.

```
function search(queryString){
  setQuery(queryString);
  getRecipe(queryString);
}

async function getRecipe(query) {
  const path = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${API_id}&app_key=${API_key}`;
  const response = await fetch(path); // <- is no longer dependent upon the state
  const data = await response.json();
  setRecipe(data.hits);
}
```

This does require moving the `path` definition inside `getRecipe()`.